# how to append a form without having to make the whole code in 1 string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form i want to append, if it's a business I append it, if it's a private person, I append the different one, but I do not want to append them all together, I want them all to have a nice effect when they come in and such, I have tried using the "put the whole form code into 1 place" method. it worked but i didnt get the result i wanted, here's my code

```
window.onload = function(){
var private = '<form action="private.php" method="post" id="privateform"><div class="form-group"  ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;"dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">כתובת אימייל</label><input  type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" class="box" placeholder="הכנס אימייל כאן" required="yes"></div><div class="form-group" ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">סיסמה</label><input   type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" class="box" placeholder="הכנס סיסמה כאן" required="yes"></div><div class="form-group" ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">הכנס סיסמה שוב</label><input   type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" class="box" placeholder="הכנס סיסמה שוב" required="yes"></div><div class="form-group" ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">שם משתמש</label><input   type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" class="box" placeholder="הכנס שם משתמש כאן" required="yes"></div><div class="form-group" ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">שם פרטי</label><input   type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="box" placeholder="הכנס שם פרטי כאן" required="yes"></div><div class="form-group" ><label dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;">שם משפחה</label><input   type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="box" placeholder="הכנס שם משפחה כאן" required="yes"></div><div><input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="הירשם" style="margin-left: 450px;"></div></form>'.split("</div>");
var privatebut = document.getElementById('private');
var popup = document.getElementById('registerform');
var jcontainer = document.getElementById('jcontainer');

privatebut.onclick = function() {

    $('#registerform').animate({left: '2000px'}, "fast");
    $('#registerform').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#jumbotron').animate({paddingBottom: "+=500px"}, 000);
    for (var i = 0; i < private.length;i++) {

        private[i] = new String(private[i]);
        $('.form-group').hide();
        $('#jcontainer').append(private[i]);
        $('.form-group').show(1000);
    }

    }; 
};
```

EDIT: I just put the form inside the php file and appended to it, sorry for the trouble guys

Comment: `var x = 'a' + 'b' + 'c'` then put newlines before/after the `+` (apply to taste/preferred style)

Comment: i did that before lol didnt work but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

never mind i just put the form inside the php file and appended to it, sry for the trouble guys

Answer (score 0):

I create a variable for each element or section I need to include (concatenate) and then add all of them to one final to check all quotations are OK (`" "` and `' '`)

```
let domInsert = "";
let divI1 = "<div class='...' id='...'>...</div>";
let button = "<input class='...' id='...'>...</input>";
let label = "<label class='...' id='...'>...</label>";
let divI2 = "<div class='...' id='...'>" + label + button + "</div>";
domInsert = divI1 + divI2
```

and then append `domInser` variable